# How to unbind jquery events that are registered after ajax load?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do I unbind / clear the events registered after Ajax load?

I have a web application in the following workflow: User clicks a button, which will launch a pop-up form via FancyBox:

```
$('.launchPopUp').click(function(){
   var url = 'something';

   $.fancybox({
     href : url,
     type : 'ajax'
   });
});
```

Where the content of the URL is a search form. Here is a simplified version:

```
This is a pop-up window.
<a id="searchButton">Search</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(document).on('click', '#searchButton', function() {
          //Do something here...
       });
    });
</script>
```

In the pop-up box, the users search the content, which results a table of records. After they select the records, the pop-up box will be closed and the selected contents will be added back to the page.

Everything works as expected. However, when the user closes the fancybox and reopen it again, I found that the jquery events are fired multiple times. I was wondering if there is any way to clear these dynamic jquery events.

Notice that it is impossible to defined the jquery event in the "base" page because the events are based on the user input (before opening the pop-up window).

Thanks!

---

Solution:

In my ajax code, I replaced "document" to "div":

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#somediv').ready(function(){
       $('#somediv').on('click', '#searchButton', function() {
          //Do something here...
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/off/ is what you're looking for

Comment: Note, you don't need to wait for the document to be ready to bind to the document itself.

Comment: Thank you. Since I have many events, is there an easy way to unbind all events? I have tried .empty() with no luck.

Comment: .off with no event names will unbind them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**.off()**](http://api.jquery.com/off/), it removes an event handler.

```
 $(document).off('click', '#searchButton');
```

To unbind all events

```
 $(selector).off();
```

From Docs

> Calling .off() with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements.

Comment: Thank you. Since I have many events, is there an easy way to unbind all events? I have tried $('.fancybox-overlay-fixed').empty() before launching fancybox, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @DerekZ.,  `$(selector).off();`